# Can I use a US visa in an expired passport, or do I need an ESTA?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, esta, b1-b2-visas

I'm an Irish citizen. My American visa runs out in 2027, but it's in an expired passport. (I do have a valid passport.) Do I need to apply for an ESTA all over?

Comment: Just to confirm, you have an actual US Visa in your old passport, not just an ESTA?

Comment: @Doc ESTAs are only valid for 2 years, so must be a visa

Comment: Is your valid passport the from the same country and of the same type (e.g. ordinary, official, diplomatic) as the passport that the visa is on?

Comment: issued from the same country (ireland) just visa is in expired one

Comment: @Stuartcarroll5yahoocom Yeah, that's fine

Comment: Is it a B visa (B-1, B-2, or B-1/B-2)?  If it is a B-1 visa, are you visiting for business?  If it is a B-2 visa, are you visiting not for business?

Answer (score 3):

No you don't need ESTA, your visa is still valid. Just present your new passport at the main page and the visa in the old passport. It's also stated in the most common airline database, TIMATIC, that this is accepted

Comment: Have made a small edit to answer to add clarity

Comment: We don't know what type of visa OP has.